# Gem 'twitter'. Parsing returns only part of the tweet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am using the twitter gem. Please tell me why I get only a part of tweet when parsing? Take a look ([live demo](https://masterpro.herokuapp.com/tweet_parser/index)).

For example:

```
Yeah, we don't want to hear from you. You've been yapping away for a million years. And by the w… 
Then, ‘for balance’ you need to also clearly and repe…
You stated as fact that there would be a #Brexit dividend,…
```

This is my code:

**controller**

```
@arr = []
client.search("@#{params[:twitter_acc]}", result_type: "recent")
      .take(params[:number_of_tweets].to_i)
      .collect do |tweet|
  @arr << tweet
            .text
            .gsub("@#{params[:twitter_acc]}", "")
            .gsub("RT :", "")
            .gsub("RT", "")
end
```

**view**

```
<% @arr.uniq.each do |line| %>
  <%= line %><br>
<% end %>
```

How can I solve this problem?
Any ideas?

UPDATE

[Tweet_parser. Result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1BqQ.png)

Comment: What does `params[:number_of_tweets]` look like?

Comment: @dinjas: I assume `"30"`, from the online demo.

Comment: Yes. 30. But I'm worried that tweets sometimes end in dots (...).

Comment: are you sure the dots aren't in the official tweets? Sometimes people do this so they can write something across multiple tweets ....

Comment: like this .....

Comment: yes, I am sure. Phrases end randomly. You can try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@arr = []
client.search("@#{params[:twitter_acc]}", result_type: "recent", tweet_mode: "extended")
      .take(params[:number_of_tweets].to_i)
      .collect do |tweet|
  @arr << tweet
            .full_text
            .gsub("@#{params[:twitter_acc]}", "")
            .gsub("RT :", "")
            .gsub("RT", "")
end
```

Comment: Look at my update. I'm sorry, but this does not work.

Comment: Andy, **tweet_mode: "extended"** does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: That's weird - according to this Github issue https://github.com/sferik/twitter/issues/880#issuecomment-358485714 I thought that tweet_mode extended was supported. It might be the way I suggested accessing the text?